# Rolling mean with conditions (interview problem)

Tags: python, hashmap

I encountered this question during an interview and can't think of a solution. This is the problem, suppose you had a dataset as follows (it goes beyond time 2 but this is just a sample to work with):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'names': ["Andy", "Bob", "Karen", "Andy", "Matt", "Sim"],
    'val': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
})
```

Write a function to calculate the mean of values up till each time point but don't count duplicate names. That is, for time 1 the mean is (1+2+3)/3, for time 2 I don't include Andy's first value of '1' I only include the most recent value so the mean for time 2 is (2+3+5+6+8)/5.

I have tried creating two dictionaries, one that stores the 'time' count and the other keeping track of 'names' and 'values' but I don't know how to proceed from there or how to come up with an efficient solution so I am not recalculating means at each step (this was another requirement for the interview).

It doesn't have to be a pandas solution, the data form can be anything you prefer. I just presented it as a pandas df.

Comment: There is actually a handy function to do this exact thing in pandas :)

    print(data['val'].mean())

You would have to filter out the values you don't want though.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be a pandas solution, the data form can be anything you prefer. I just presented it as a pandas df.

Comment: @Ria, if `time` (*group*) 3 has not *"Andy"* in the `names`, should the mean include Andy's value from `time` 1, `time` 2, both, or neither ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to compute the [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html) of the values up to the current time, while considering only the last seen duplicates (*if any*). If so, here is one potential option that uses [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) inside a *for-loop* to build the expanding windows :

```
# uncomment if necessary
# data.sort_values("time", inplace=True)

to_keep = "last" # duplicate

means = {}
for t in data["time"].unique():
    window = data.loc[data["time"].le(t)]
    m = ~window["names"].duplicated(to_keep)
    means[t] = window.loc[m, "val"].mean()
```

Output (`means`) :

```
{ # time|mean
    1: 2.0, #  (1+2+3)/3
    2: 4.8, #  (2+3+5+6+8)/5
}
```